# Cover n points with n disjoint unit disks

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

This is a problem I saw on [Peter Winkler's column on communication of the ACM](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/9/98023-puzzled-solutions-and-sources/fulltext)(might be under a pay wall). It is open.

What is the largest $n$, such that you can always cover a given set of $n$ points with $n$ disjoint unit disks?

I believe the current upper bound is $60$.

I would like to know more reference on this problem. Currently I don't even know what field would study problems like this.

Comment: Discrete Geometry?

Comment: Discrete and/or computational geometry are generic labels for this kind of problem.

Comment: A related question on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20558/what-is-the-minimum-n-for-which-there-exist-n-points-in-the-plane-that-cannot-be

Comment: The lower bound was improved to $12$ and it seems that the upper bound can be improved to $44$, see the paper linked in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519128/covering-eleven-dots-in-the-plane-with-eleven-coins-counterexample/1521677#1521677) answer.

Comment: The third "$n$" in the question should be dropped, i.e. the question should be "What's the largest $n$ such that you can always cover a given set of $n$ points with disjoint unit disks?" Any disks that cover no points are irrelevant, and if you insist that each of $n$ disks contains a unique point, then the answer is 2: for a sufficiently small equilateral triangle, there are no three disjoint circles, each containing one vertex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a claim of a reduction from 60 to 54. An abstract of Yosuke Okayama, Exclusive covering of point set by unit disks, is available on the web.

Comment: The full text of the thesis of Yosuke Okayama is available [here](http://hdl.handle.net/10119/9654). It written entirely in Japanese, though. From the abstract I gather that it is the text you're referring to.

Comment: Thanks for the link! :) The paper refer to Veit Elser's paper, which is the best thing available for English speakers, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.3468v1

Answer (score 2):

The 54 result you refer to is available in the proceedings of the Canadian Conference on Computational Geometry.    But the result has already been improved slightly.    Look for it on arXiv  soon.