# Covering eleven dots in the plane with eleven coins - counterexample?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, examples-counterexamples, plane-geometry

The questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6737/covering-ten-dots-on-a-table-with-ten-equal-sized-coins-explanation-of-proof) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519060/prove-that-using-10-coins-is-enough-to-cover-any-10-points-in-a-plane) relate to the question as to whether, given ten equally sized coins and a configuration of ten dots in the plane, there is a way of placing the coins so that they cover all the dots without overlapping.

The solution given depends on the fact that a close-packing of circles in the plane covers more than ninety percent of the area, and then uses probability to show that the expected number of dots covered by a random close-packing of coins is greater than nine, so some particular configuration must allow all ten dots to be covered.

But such an argument does not go through for eleven dots - and I was wondering if there were a counterexample in this case (or for some number greater than eleven). The margin is quite low for eleven, so a counterexample would have to be quite delicate.

Comment: Maybe I should give a larger bounty for this. It seems to me to be a great problem with an elementary statement, at which the bounds of elementary reasoning are tested. Exceptional configurations are likely to have interesting properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Naoki Inaba coin-covering problem. The paper [Covering Points with Disjoint Unit Disks](http://2012.cccg.ca/papers/paper13.pdf) shows a set of 45 points that can't be covered with unit disks. I believe that was beaten, but I don't recall the details.

Comment: Thank you, that's the kind of thing I was looking for, and indeed the kind of proof I had in my mind to try out if I found some time. They show also that twelve points can be covered.